# PAHO MQTT Android client for service and MainActivity BinderProxy

Tags: android, service, client, mqtt, paho

I am new into MQTT and PAHO MQTT Client library too. I am looking for best practice with usage of android client library.

I have application with background service that publish informations to mqtt broker on background. So I create one mqtt client in background service and publish of messages is working ok.

But I also need mqtt client in Main activity for receiving different informations from mqtt broker. When I try to create client in Main activity (in main thread) than I receive exception "java.lang.ClassCastException: android.os.BinderProxy cannot be cast to ...". I found some information about that problem, and I think that problem is in multiple mqtt services in application, but I don't know how to share one instance of mqtt client between service and main application - and I don't know if it is right solution.

In manifest I have this:

```
...
<service android:name=".MyBackgroundService" android:process=":remote" />
<service android:name="org.eclipse.paho.android.service.MqttService" android:process=":remote" >
...
```

Please can you help me to right solutions?

Thank you.

Comment: You can bind to your service in your activity, implement some methods in your service to send message and receive message via callback

Comment: Thank you, I can do this for same MQTT broker. But what if I need connect main app to different broker?

Comment: Yes, I would like to have. But when I try connect second MqttAndroidClient to second server(in main thread), I've got BinderProxy exception.

Answer (score -3):

You can use EventBus for send messages by Services to Activities.